# How to write the SQL statement to derive Consecutive worked days?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am working this on MS SQL. Anyone knows how to derive the consecutive_d column? Consecutive days should be solely based on ENTER_DT regardless of times. And if an employee enters many times in the same day it is still counted as one consecutive days.

```
PASS_M|  ENTER_DT................|CONSECUTIVE_D
Boo K K    5/1/2012 11:55:00 PM       1  
Boo K K    5/2/2012 11:30:00 PM       2  
Boo K K    5/4/2012 10:30:00 AM       1  
LIAW S     4/30/2012 11:48:52 PM      1  
LIAW S     5/1/2012 00:11:07 AM       2  
LIAW S     5/1/2012 12:32:07 AM       2  
LIAW S     5/1/2012 4:42:02 AM        2    
LIAW S     5/2/2012 1:10:09 AM        3  
LIAW S     5/2/2012 1:43:06 AM        3   
LIAW S     5/4/2012 2:17:47 AM        1
```

Update: this is what i have tried:

```
SELECT PASS_M, ENTRY_DT, DATEDIFF(D, MIN(ENTRY_DT) OVER (PARTITION BY PASS_M), ENTRY_DT) + 1 AS CONSECTUTIVE_DAYS
INTO         TEMP_TARGET
FROM         TEMP_5
ORDER BY PASS_M, ENTRY_DT;
```

Comment: oh, i tot i always up the vote if it is helpful. What if it does help but its not the answer to my qns? what shld i do? sry i am a newbie

Comment: If none of the answers are "the answer", but you figure it out then you should post your own answer with the resolution and mark it as the answer.

Comment: For this particular question, what have you tried?

Comment: @abatishev can teach me how to insert table or code in Stack? I read the formatting notes but still unable to apprehend it. Make it simple? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

`SELECT *, CONVERT(DATE,GETDATE()) AS DateOnly, SUM(CONSECUTIVE_D) as CONSECUTIVE_SUM GROUP BY DateOnly;`

This allows you to group elements by Date by extracting it from the datetime and then the sum of `CONSECUTIVE_D` will be `CONSECUTIVE_SUM`

I hope that's what you were looking for :)

You can build your own custom query from this one!
Requested Update

```
SELECT
PASS_M, 
ENTRY_DT, 
(DATEDIFF(D, MIN(ENTRY_DT) OVER (PARTITION BY PASS_M), ENTRY_DT) + 1) AS CONSECTUTIVE_DAYS,
CONVERT(DATE,ENTRY_DT) AS DateOnly,
SUM(CONSECUTIVE_DAYS) as CONSECUTIVE_SUM

INTO         TEMP_TARGET
FROM         TEMP_5
GROUP BY DateOnly
ORDER BY PASS_M;
```

In my head, that should do the trick! Don't ORDER BY `ENTRY_DT`, you now want to GROUP BY DateOnly

Here's a link about how to [Turn datetime into date](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2012/09/12/sql-server-get-date-and-time-from-current-datetime-sql-in-sixty-seconds-025-video/) :)

Comment: Hi, i have tried urs but it doesnt work. Maybe its because i do not know how to apply. Do you mind altering your solution from my above statement that i have tried?

Comment: Hi, after trying urs again, i got invalid column name for CONSECUTIVE_D and DateOnly. I also got an error "type date is not a defined system type" I am using SQL server 2005

Comment: Oh, I assumed that you were using a newer version! Use the 2005 version of the datetime conversion in the link I handed. Don't forget you replace getDate() by ENTRY_DT ! Everything should work just fine ;)

Comment: Still cant, maybe its the problem of my software. I honestly think your solution will work for others. Thanks for ur help.

Comment: Sorry for not being able to do more :/ . I already did something much similar in a resent project and it worked flawlessly. meh

Comment: Btw how do u SUM(CONSECUTIVE_D) when u do not have that column yet. I am trying to get the logic behind how u do it that create new statement in 2005

Comment: Yes! The column `CONSECUTIVE_DAYS` exist (well virtually)! That's what the statement `AS` does

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20982/discussion-between-10e5x-and-marctrem)

Answer (score 1):

I would truncate the date, `trunc_date(enter_dt)`, then count repeated values with a GROUP BY or PARTITION BY.

Edit: For SQL Server, as Aaron mentioned, use `cast(getDate() As Date)` note `trunc_date`. The guy has a 33% acceptance as of this writing, so I didn't want to think too hard. :)

Comment: `trunc_date`? In SQL Server?

Comment: I did not realize that i should mark post as answer even it does not answer to my qns, but helped me in getting what i want. I always up the vote. Now that i know, i will accept those that helped me derived my answer and post my solution. What if both are correct answer?

Comment: @10e5x: This is probably for another thread, but if the other posts did not answer your questions, `you did the right thing`. As you ask more, I think you'll find the bulk get answered and your ratio will improve.
The context is that many new users do not mark even correct answers, so future visitors do not have the benefit of knowing what worked to solve the problem for the poster.

Comment: Ok thanks charles. For all other user who have similar problem as mine, please post ur version of your SQL server. I am using 2005 and i have problems using both of the 2 answers but i believe both will work:)